# Fineuploader - iphone issue (unrecoverable error)

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, fine-uploader

I can't get the fineuploader to work with iphone while it works fine on ipad , all I get is "unrecoverable error - this browser does not permit uploading of any kind". I also tested the safari on iphone simulator on browserstack where it was actually working. I am kind of in wrong way here and would appreciate help.

The url for the fineuploader is:

http://gruppu.com/uploadform2

Thanks,

Jorge

Comment: Also wanted to mention that I didn't found any working demo for iphone , all fineuploader demo pages didn't load on mobile safari :(

Comment: Installed xcode and tried with ios simulator, un/fortunately it works ..

Comment: What version of iOS? Note that <6 does not allow file uploading of any kind. See http://docs.fineuploader.com/browser-support.html

Comment: Version: 5.1.1  (9B206)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS <6 does not support the file input element at all. The workaround is to upgrade to iOS6+ which has support for the file input element on Safari, and thus, file uploading.